# Threading in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

I have initialized 250 threads at a time and they are returning back to update some data in the database. I am using Postgresql database in my rails 2 application. I have set Pool size 100 and max connections 100 but the problem is after 100 connections remaining threads are causing problem like "FATAL ERROR: Too many clients". So now i want is as soon as any thread complete its process then kill that thread. SO to achieve this what should i do?

Here is my code:

```
consider detail = "contains 250 items in an array"
 threads = []
      detail.each do |item|
          threads << Thread.new( item) do | item |
           # block of code
          end
      end
   threads.each { | t | t.join }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Rails 2.2 where connection pooling has been implemented. Check this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_2_release_notes.html#connection-pooling

and this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

Comment: I have used the same approach but still getting same error. Please suggest how to i handle maximum connections using threading?